# Woocommerce analytics not showing sales after upgrade

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Yesterday I upgraded WooCommerce from 4+ to the latest version. Apparently all was working well but one thing I noticed is that the “net sales this month” area in the WooCommerce Status dashboard panel shows $0.00. I know for a fact that we’ve had sales yesterday and today, and these sales are visible if I go to Woocommerce->Reports. However, it's like Analytics is not measuring anything anymore. Not only is it not counting sales that took place yesterday and today but it's not counting any sales from the past either.

Any ideas on how can I fix this? I have already cleared the analytics cache and imported historical data but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

was having the same issue but came across this on a wordpress forum https://wordpress.org/support/topic/7-6-update-bug-dashboard-view-analytics-malfunction/ and it worked incase you're still having the same issue

If you go to Analytics > Settings, then check Completed under Actionable Statuses that restored the order data for me.

I suspect this should be checked by default but has been missed in this version.